# fast key value store with records on disk(not in memory)

Tags: database, distributed, nosql

Please for the business, I am looking for a fast key value store system with the following features:

-) records on disk (not in memory): when a key/value pair is created I want to store it directly on disk because the datas is sensible to any ram failure and billions of key/value can be created per days.

-)  can be distributed (homogenous master-slave sharing nothing with the possibility to define a redundant master server if the main  master fails) and each site partially replicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a opinion based question.

Aerospike seems to meet this criteria. They have both community and enterprise addition. Aerospike is fast and writes to disk. It is best to use with ssd, rather than rotational disks.

Comment: It's an in memory one!

Comment: It writes to disk. From aerospikes [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage):  
`Aerospike determines where to store data based on the Storage engine configured for the namespace. These engines determine if the data will be persisted to disk, reside in memory, or both.`